# Expected value of a biased game

Tags: probability, puzzle, game-theory

I heard this puzzle a while back and wasn't sure how to answer it:

You play a game whose cost to play goes up at every round, and there are 2 possible outcomes.
Winning and losing.
You win with 60% likelyhood and lose with 40% chance at all rounds.

Round 1 - Costs \$1 to play
On the first round, if you win, you win another \$1.
If you lose, you lose your \$1.

Round 2 - Cost \$2 to play
On the second round, if you win, you win another \$1.
If you lose, you lose your \$2.

Round 3 - Cost \$3 to play
On the Thirdround, if you win, you win another \$1.
If you lose, you lose your \$3.

What are the expected values at each round, and how do you calculate them?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is the cost of the game refunded if you win?  If not...well, I don't think anyone would ever play this game.

Comment: Can you keep playing if you lose a round?

Comment: It's a losing proposition as rounds increase and the only round that would make sense is the first round.

Answer (score 1):

Cost \$2 and you win another \$1 means that if you win you cash \$3?, Right? This because usually the cost of a game is never reimbursed. Have I understood well? And you want to know the expected gain at EACH round? This independently about what happened before?

Under these assumptions, the three expectations are the following:

$$\mathbb{E}[R_1]=1\times0.6-1\times0.4$$

$$\mathbb{E}[R_2]=1\times0.6-2\times0.4$$

$$\mathbb{E}[R_3]=1\times0.6-3\times0.4$$